# Git show submodule revision

Tags: git, git-submodules

***The situation:*** I have a remote repository (which I don't manage), which includes a couple of submodules.

I want to know the submodule revision corresponding to a specific repository revision.

That is, I have a repo **REPO_A** which I can work with **REV_A1** or **REV_A2**.
It has in a folder named **repob** a submodule linked to **REPO_B**, in **REV_A1** it points to **REV_B1** from **REPO_B** and in **REV_A2** it points to **REV_B2**.

***The workaround***: I can:

- Checkout **REPO_A** at **REV_A1**
- `git submodule update --init repob` inside the repo folder (that will create **repob** folder and check it out)
- `cd repob && git rev-parse HEAD` and I'll get **REV_B1**

***The question:*** Is there some inexpensive way to do this? Similarly to `git archive` to checkout only one file, Something like `git <magic-words> REPO_A REV_A1 repob` that outputs **REV_B1**? I don't want to checkout the entire repository just to see the revision **REV_B1** corresponding to **REV_A1**.

Thanks.